# pyTelegramBotAPI метод send_message возвращает только первое значение из словаря

Tags: python, json, telebot, структуры-данных

Всем привет!
Пишу бота на pyTelegramBotAPI. В одном из вызовов метода send_message в качестве текстового параметра пытаюсь вывести значение, возвращаемое функцией в виде списка.

```
def get_price_and_tariff(zone=dcv_zone, type=dcv_auto_type, sum_insured=dcv_suminsured):
    import json
    with open('DCV.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if zone == 'zone1':
        if type == 'type1':
            if sum_insured == '50000':
                print(data['zone1']['type1']['50000']['KV'][0])
                return data['zone1']['type1']['50000']['KV'][0]
```

json имеет такую структуру:

```
{
    "zone1": {
        "type1": {
            "50000": {
                "KV": [
                    [
                        "0,19%",
                        "95"
                    ],
                    [
                        "0,2%",
                        "100"
                    ]
                ]
            },
```

print отрабатывает нормально возвращая ['0,19%', '95'], а send_message отправляет в телеграм только "0,19%", а второй элемент не отправляет. Подскажите куда копать....
Спасибо.

Comment: возможно проблема в том что вы пытаетесь отправить список, а не текст. попробуйте преобразовать этот список в текст и отправить

Comment: спасибо, помогло...